# What is the difference between "percent" and "percentages"?

Tags: plural-forms, singular

I don't know what the difference between "percent" and "percentage" is.

Do they mean two different things and do they have different uses?
I would like to know what kind of situations each word would be used in.

It will be helpful if you could provide some examples. Thank you.

Comment: The difference is the same as the difference between "grams" and "weight". A more similar example would be "tonnes" and "tonnage".

Answer (score 1):

Percentage is used when it's an undefined amount, and percentages is the plural form.

> In large percentage of cases...
> We use percentages to compare things.

Per cent (or %) is used with a number.

> 20 per cent of the dogs were male.

A good rule of thumb is that per cent (or %) can be replaced with "out of 100".